# Looking for a matching date from postgres, that would match current date

Tags: python, postgresql, datetime

I am looking for a specific date, and if it matches, I want it to start doing other stuff, but I have no clue, how can I check if the dates match.

```
    # Dates look like this
    # Date = '25-04-2022 08:00:00' 
    # CurrentDate = 2022-04-25 14:45:21.229083
    #    
    CurrentDate = datetime.now()
    
    print(CurrentDate)
    
    Date=read_database_test()
    
    ExpectedDate = datetime.strptime(Date, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
    print(ExpectedDate)
    
    if CurrentDate > ExpectedDate:
        print("Date missed")
    else:
        print("Date not missed")
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert `datetime.now()` to string and parse it again, it already is a `datetime` object.

The Error says the format used for parsing does not match the given data.`'2022-04-25 14:01:47.950180' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`

This format is looks like ISO 8601 with space instead of 'T' between date and time sections. [docs: datetime.fromisoformat](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromisoformat)

```
CurrentDate = datetime.now()
print(CurrentDate)

Date=read_database_test()

ExpectedDate = datetime.fromisoformat(Date)
print(ExpectedDate)

if CurrentDate > ExpectedDate:
    print("Date missed")
else:
    print("Date not missed")
```